# ListBox.Invoke() in .Net Core 3.1 in WindowsFormApp with thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, listbox, .net-core-3.1

I want to add some items to listbox with a thread or backgroundworker in C# .Net core 3.1. But when I call PridaniDoLB(ListBox lb, Messages messages) function in a loop my program is not responding. And when I am in Debug mod, I get an error message. How can I fix that?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJJcj.png)

1)

```
    private async Task Client_Log(LogMessage args)
    {
        listStandard.Add(new Messages("Standard", args.Source.ToString(), args.Message.ToString(), DateTime.Now));
        PridaniDoLB(lb_standard, listStandard[listStandard.Count() - 1]);
    }
    public delegate void Update();
    public void PridaniDoLB(ListBox lb, object messages)
    {
        if (lb.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //lb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            //{
            //    lb.Items.Add(messages);
            //}));
            lb.Invoke(new Update(() => lb.Items.Add(messages)));
        }
        else
        {
            lb.Items.Add(messages);
        }
    }
```

2)MainAsync

```
        private async Task MainAsync()
    {
        client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
        });
        commands = new CommandService(new CommandServiceConfig
        {
            CaseSensitiveCommands = true,
            DefaultRunMode = RunMode.Async,
            LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
        });
        client.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived;

        await commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), serviceProvider);

        //joinAudioManager.JoinTask();

        client.Ready += Client_Ready;
        client.Log += Client_Log;


        string token = "";
        using (var stream = new FileStream((Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1"
            , @"Core\Data\Token.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var readToken = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            token = readToken.ReadToEnd();
        }
        await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        await client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }
```

3) Class Messages

```
class Messages
{
    public string nazev, text, result;
    public DateTime cas;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now} at {args.Source}] {args.Message}");

        return $"[{cas} at {text}] {result}";
    }

    public Messages(string nazev, string text, string result, DateTime cas)
    {
        this.nazev = nazev;
        this.text = text;
        this.result = result;
        this.cas = cas;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing async about `Client_Log`, start with removing `async` and return `void` instead of `Task`.

Comment: I added mainasync

Comment: You aren't returning a Task. It's not async. It has nothing to do with main async.

Comment: I know  `client.Log += Client_Log;`, but what about this